# Access-Control-Allow-Origin from Custom Embedded HTML in Wix

Tags: javascript, html, cors, velo

I am trying to call my backend http-function from Custom Embedded HTML, the problem is that the request is coming from https://example.filesusr.com, because of that i am getting CORS error:

```
https://example.com/_functions/myfunction' from origin 'https://example.filesusr.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How do i allow requests from this origin? Is there an alternate solution to call backend function from Custom Embedded HTML element in Wix?